# Allow UFW access from IP wildcard

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I would like to allow access from IP address based upon wildcards

e.g.

`64.201.52*`

How can this be done with UFW?

Have tried `sudo ufw allow from 64.201.52.*`

Comment: Something similar was covered at Ask Ubuntu: [UFW - allow range of IP addresees?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646424/ufw-allow-range-of-ip-addresees)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The jargon is not an ip-address *wildcard* but typically you grant/deny access to a **network range** or a (group of) **subnet(s)**.

The equivalent to 64.201.52.* formatted as a subnet is then either `64.201.52.0/24` or `64.201.52.0/255.255.255.0`

Comment: `64.201.0.0/255.255.0.0` or `64.201.0.0/16` is that correct for last 2 ?